# Make lower case for pattern in TextEdit

Tags: textedit

If I select text using a pattern in TextEdit how do I transform that selected text?  I can't get anything in the Transform menu to work when text is selected like this.

I am using a pattern to find and highlight text.

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming that by "a pattern", you mean when you search for some text, and it highlights the matches?

Comment: Yes.  For my example I was using an actual pattern with "Any Word Characters" but same issue as with just using text.

Comment: Can you, pls, show screenshot? I tried to make what you wrote here and still have 'Make lower case' available in menu. What's not working for you?

Comment: I added a screenshot.  I'm creating a pattern to highlight matches.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, as the 'selected text' is your search parameter, not your document contents.

You'd need to use Replace & set your desired capitalisation change in there - for which you could copy paste into replace & use the very function you're trying to use in the main text.

[image]

Comment: I'm using a pattern to find & replace.  http://mattgemmell.com/images/find_patterns_lion/find_patterns_menu.jpg

Comment: Then you can't. The above still applies, but the results are far more unpredictable.